# Android - Adding horizontal scroll in a layout with multiple Items

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I want to create a layout which has multiple views in it. Currently I have 3tabs, in one of which I want to be able to scroll a specific part of the layout which contains two textviews and an Image.
I have tried using ViewPager , HorizontalScrollView but I havenot been able to scroll this part of my layout. Here is a design of my layout

[some images][scroll view]

[table 1]

[table 2]

[tab1][tab2][tab3]

the code that I have ran for gesture detection

```
public class RegionView extends HorizontalScrollView implements View.OnTouchListener{
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 5;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 300;
    private ArrayList<ArticleList> mItems= new ArrayList<ArticleList>();
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private int mActiveFeature = 0;

    public RegionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setItems();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RegionView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        internalWrapper = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
        internalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.regionll1);
        featureLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(myContext,R.layout.regionview1,null);

        setItems();
    }

    public void setItems(){

        showToast("setItem Called");

        internalLayout.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

        for(int i = 0; i< mItems.size();i++){
            internalLayout.addView(featureLayout);
        }

        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL ){
                    int scrollX = getScrollX();
                    int featureWidth = v.getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = ((scrollX + (featureWidth/2))/featureWidth);
                    int scrollTo = mActiveFeature*featureWidth;
                    smoothScrollTo(scrollTo, 0);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        public boolean isRightToLeft = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {

                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    int featureWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = (mActiveFeature < (mItems.size() - 1))? mActiveFeature + 1:mItems.size() -1;
                    smoothScrollTo(mActiveFeature*featureWidth, 0);
                    isRightToLeft=true;
                    return true;
                }else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    int featureWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
                    mActiveFeature = (mActiveFeature > 0)? mActiveFeature - 1:0;
                    smoothScrollTo(mActiveFeature*featureWidth, 0);
                    showToast("Gesture on right swipe");
                    isRightToLeft=false;
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fling", "There was an error processing the Fling event:" + e.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My XML file with the tabhost , I have splitted the code in 2 parts to show the place where I am implementing the Horizontalscroll view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TabHost
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/main_bckground"
       >
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
      <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </RelativeLayout>   
        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/Orange"
                >
        </TabWidget>
             <FrameLayout
                   android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <!--First Tab-->
                <LinearLayout
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:id="@+id/tabyourcity"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:paddingLeft="0dip"
                     android:paddingRight="0dip" >
            </LinearLayout>
               <!—Second Tab-->
               <LinearLayout
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:id="@+id/tabnepal"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:id = "@+id/nepalpageview"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                 <RelativeLayout
                   android:orientation="vertical"
                           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                      <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/loadContainernepal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#414141"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/loadingTextnepal"        
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="  Data is Loading...." 
                                android:textColor="#FFF"
 />                                                                                                                   <ProgressBar
                              android:id="@+id/progressBar2Nepal"
                              android:layout_width="25dip"
                              android:layout_height="25dip"
                  android:indeterminate="true"                                                        
                              android:visibility="visible"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="160dip"                        
                              style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                            />                                                                                                                         
                          </LinearLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout> 
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relativelayouttop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                  <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tv_sunrisetime"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:text="rise time"
                       android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                  <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/img_SUNRISE"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:text="SUNRISE"
                      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                       android:textColor="@color/Orange"
                       android:textSize="18sp" >
                     </TextView>
                  <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/img_SUNRISE"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="30dp"
                       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                       android:paddingTop="5dp"
                       android:src="@drawable/sunriseicon" />
                 <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_sunset"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_sunset"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/img_sunset"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SUNSET"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/Orange"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                   <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/tv_sunsettime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_sunrise"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SET time"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_sunset"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_sunrisetime"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_sunrisetime"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_sunrisetime"
                    android:src="@drawable/sunseticon" />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:gravity="right" >
                          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                                 android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

the code works fine when I give all the image and text field in this layout, 
but since I need to check the value and then place the texts and image here while scrolled I’m having a problem implementing this

```
<!--   <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/scroll_linearlayout "
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >
                        <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/regionll1 "
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >
                             <TextView
                                      android:id="@+id/tv_regionname"
                                      android:layout_width="130dp"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:gravity="center"
                                      android:text="Hilly Region"
                                      android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                      android:textSize="18sp" />
                          <ImageView
                                   android:id="@+id/img_region"
                                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                   android:layout_height="75dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/iconsresized5" />
                             <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_regiontemp"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
                             android:id="@+id/regionll2 "
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                              android:id="@+id/regionll3 "
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:orientation="vertical" >
                        </LinearLayout> 
                          </LinearLayout> -->
                         </HorizontalScrollView>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>     
        </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp" >
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:background="@color/Orange"
                            android:gravity="center" >
                            <ImageView
                          android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                             android:layout_width="25dp"
                             android:layout_height="20dp"
                          android:src="@drawable/rainfall_stastastics" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                             android:text="Rainfall Statistics"
                             android:textColor="#ffffff"
                             android:textSize="16sp" />
                       </TableRow>
           <TableRow
                           android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/tbl_background" >
                        <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                           android:layout_width="4dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/bullet" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Total this month to date            "
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_totalrainfall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                                </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
                        <TableLayout>
                        </TableLayout>
                 </LinearLayout>
               </LinearLayout>
                 </LinearLayout>
             </FrameLayout>
           </RelativeLayout>
        </TabHost>
```

I want a scrollview like the one we get with iphone by viewpager

Comment: Could you post the layout class that you're trying to use for processing? Also, rather than copy the iPhone's design, Android has it's own design guidelines on how to implement things. Instead, is there an example of an existing Android app which performs the same behaviour that you're trying to implement?

Comment: @MattTaylor I have added the xml code, I have commented the code inside the horizontal view coz I'm not sure about it.I did saw the use of gallery for this purpose and also I did found one of 'JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator ' but I didn't wanted to use an external library for this purpose.